# Get all attachments by custom taxonomy - term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, attachments, terms

I want to make custom taxonomy (gallery) and terms (name1, name2, name3...)
Add images into media tab and then retrieve all images from same term.
Look like simple task, but I cant manage it.

I registered new (custom) tax, added some terms to image, but I cannot retrieve any of them. Searched for two days for solution, just can't put all pieces all together.

I want to get list of terms first, and then get list of images from this list.

Answer (score 2):

To get all images from the same term you can use WP_Query with the "tax_query" argument:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'attachment',
);

$args['tax_query'] = array(
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY',
    'terms' => array( 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_TERM' ),
    'field' => 'slug',
),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```